# Is there a SSH client for Ubuntu with File Manager?

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, sftp

Is there a SSH client for Ubuntu with File Manager facility like Bitvise SSH Client?

I tried Putty, but it doesn't include the UI based file management?

Comment: Do you mean an [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) client? I personally use Midnight Commander for that.

Comment: SFTP file transfer client.

Comment: You can also use your system's default file manager (nautilus/nemo/thunar etc.). Just enter sftp://login@domain/ in the address bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `sshfs` instead of using something like `sftp://`; It's a small package, install it using:

```
sudo apt install sshfs
```

Then mount your remote machine using something like:

```
mkdir ~/sshfs
sshfs root@192.168.x.x:/home ~/sshfs
```

- `/home` is the path you want to mount, you can use whatever path you want.

Now you have access to your files using your default file manager, you can even play music/video etc using  your default applications and work with your files on remote machine in real time.

After you were finished run:

```
fusermount -u ~/sshfs
```

to unmount the mount point.

The advantage over `sftp` is that you don't need to move files to your local machine to edit/run/play them you can use them as they are located on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open-source [redial](https://github.com/taypo/redial) with midnight commander support, totally works on terminal

```
pip3 install redial
```